# NumberFormatException: For input string: "XXX,XX" in TextField, related to locale

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, javafx-2, locale

I have a controller class that loads scenes accordingly selected choices. I called it "CMenu".

```
/*** Other methods that load other menu entries ***/

/**
 * Menu de Usuarios
 * 
 * @param event
 * @throws Exception
 */
public void menuUsuarios(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Usuarios.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/styles/application.css").toExternalForm());
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Menu de usuarios");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        // Llamamos a la ventana de menu
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Menu de Inventario
 * 
 * @param event
 * @throws Exception
 */
public void menuProductos(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
    try {
        Locale.setDefault(new Locale("es"));
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Productos.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/styles/application.css").toExternalForm());
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Menu de Productos");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Menu de Empleados
 * 
 * @param event
 * @throws Exception
 */
public void menuEmpleados(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Empleados.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/styles/application.css").toExternalForm());
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Menu de Empleados");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    /*** Other methods that load other menu entries ***/
```

There's "products" menu, that looks like this.

[Product menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB1il.png)

When I type the cost and set a profit the price get calculated using onKeyEvent, in this kind of format: "123.456,99". And vice-versa.

```
txtUtil.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            if (txtCosto.getText() != null && txtUtil.getText() != null && txtPrecio.getText() != null) {
                try {
                    costo = Double.parseDouble(txtCosto.getText());
                    util = Double.parseDouble(txtUtil.getText());
                    precio = (costo / (((util / 100) - 1) * (-1)));
                    txtPrecio.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f", precio)));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error en algo");
            }

        }
    });
        txtPrecio.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            if (txtCosto.getText() != null && txtUtil.getText() != null && txtPrecio.getText() != null) {
                try {
                    costo = Double.parseDouble(txtCosto.getText());
                    precio = Double.parseDouble(txtPrecio.getText());
                    util = ((costo / precio) - 1) * -100;
                    txtUtil.setText(String.valueOf((double) Math.round(util * 100) / 100));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So when I release the key in the price TextField I get this error (among others but not to mention them here).

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "21428,57"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
at ajfmo.sislic.controlador.CProductos$3.handle(CProductos.java:164)
at ajfmo.sislic.controlador.CProductos$3.handle(CProductos.java:1)
```

I see the trouble is at ajfmo.sislic.controlador.CProductos$3.handle(CProductos.java:164), but I figured out that the real problem is about the default locale that the scene is getting, I changed to en and the problem disappears, but what if **I want to keep in my default locale and not get that error?**

Besides the records are saved into a MySQL database, **will I have problems If I changed that locale?**

Many thanks, in advance for reading this.

Comment: Before parsing you can check what is locale and it's decimal delimiter and then just call `.replace()` on `getText()` and replace it to to right one.

Comment: 1. Don't use key event handlers to respond to changes in a text field (what happens if the user pastes data with a mouse?). Register a listener with the `textProperty()` instead. 2. Don't mix Swing (e.g. your `JOptionPane`) and JavaFX; this will hang on many systems. 3. Use a [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) instance, which can parse (as well as format) text to numbers, accounting for the locale.

Comment: @DavidS. thanks for your suggestion! but that's not the approach that I'm looking for.

Comment: @James_D Hello Jim! thank you! your suggestions are very welcome and appreciated, I'm working on it now, I'm having other issues in result with your answer but I think I can solve them. :+1:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse text to a numeric value in a locale-dependent way (including grouping characters and locale-dependent decimal separators), use a [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) object.

Here's a very quick demo, which should be easy to adapt for your application:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DecimalFormatTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        // use system default locale:
        // NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance();

        // or specify the locale explicitly:
        NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance(new Locale("es", "VE"));

        String text = "123.456,01" ;
        double value = format.parse(text).doubleValue();
        System.out.println("Parsed value as double: " +value);
        System.out.println("Value formatted again as text: " + format.format(value));
    }

}
```

This gives the output

```
Parsed value as double: 123456.01
Value formatted again as text: 123.456,01
```

Comment: This did the trick and solve the error that I was getting. Now I'm getting a bug but that's something that I can solve by myself I think. I'm refactoring the class and methods to see if there's no problem with HQL and that value with a comma. Many thanks for your reply sir, Saludos, desde Venezuela as you already know!

Answer (score -1):

Double.valueOf, and by extension Double.parseDouble, does not consider international representations of floating point numbers.  The javadoc on Double.valueOf states the following:

**To interpret localized string representations of a floating-point value, use subclasses of java.text.NumberFormat.**

To get a localized version of NumberFormat, use it's getInstance method.  So, the following two lines in your code,

```
costo = Double.parseDouble(txtCosto.getText());
precio = Double.parseDouble(txtPrecio.getText());
```

Should be changed to,

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(); // Use JVM default locale
costco = nf.parse(txtCosto.getText()).doubleValue();
precio = nf.parse(txtPrecio.getText()).doubleValue();
```